# Named arguments without natural defaults in Julia

Tags: function, arguments, julia

The question is about 'best practice' in Julia. I have read [this](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/485) and [this](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/functions/). I have a function

```
function discount_rate(n, fv, pmt, pv; pmt_type = 0)
...
end
```

The problem right now is I have to call the method like so

```
discount_rate( 10, 10, 10, -10 )
```

It's not clear what these arguments mean -- even I forget. What I'd love to do is write

```
discount_rate( n = 10, fv = 10, pmt = 10, pv = -10 )
```

That's clearer: easier to read and understand. But I can't define my method by making these arguments `keywords` arguments or `optional` arguments because they don't have **natural** defaults. From the point of view of design, is there a recommended way around this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Could do the following:

```
function discount_rate(;n=nothing,fv=nothing,pmt=nothing,pv=nothing,pmt_type=0)
    if n == nothing || fv == nothing || pmt == nothing || pv == nothing
        error("Must provide all arguments")
    end
    discount_rate(n,fv,pmt,pv,pmt_type=pmt_type)
end

function discount_rate(n, fv, pmt, pv; pmt_type = 0)
    #...
end
```

Comment: Thanks, Iain. Also, have found your Julia video tutorials on Youtube very useful.

Comment: is it possible to do something similar to the above with named arguments but also specify the type, i.e., `; n::Int64, fv::Float64, ...`?

Comment: specifically in v0.6; this seems like the standard way for v1.0

Answer (score 1):

It is worth noting that Julia introduced [mandatory keyword arguments](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/#Keyword-Arguments-1) in v0.7:

```
julia> foo(; a) = a
foo (generic function with 1 method)

julia> foo()
ERROR: UndefKeywordError: keyword argument a not assigned
Stacktrace:
 [1] foo() at ./REPL[1]:1
 [2] top-level scope at none:0
```

Answer (score 0):

As a follow up, it got a little tedious to have to (re)write the keywords-only counterparts for the functions I already had. Inspired by Iain's answer above, I wrote a macro that essentially does the same thing...

```
macro make_kwargs_only( func, args... )
 quote
  function $( esc( func ) )( ; args... )
   func_args = [ arg[2] for arg in args ]
   return $( esc( func ) )( func_args... )
  end
 end
end
```

And so, for example

```
f( a, b ) = a/b
@show f( 1, 2 )
f(1,2) => 0.5
```

Creating its keywords-only counterpart gives

```
@make_kwargs_only f a b
@show f( a = 1, b = 2 )
f(a=1,b=2) => 0.5
```

Note however this is not the general case. Here the order of the argument is crucial. Ideally I would've liked the macro to work the same way for both `f( a = 1, b = 2 )` and `f( b = 2, a = 1 )`. That is not the case.

```
@show f( b = 2, a = 1 )
f(b=2,a=1) => 2.0
```

So for now, as a hack, I use `methods( f )` if I can't remember the order of the arguments. Any suggestion on how to rewrite the macro to handle both cases is welcome...maybe a way to sort `func_args` within the macro's function definition based on the function signature of `func`?

Answer (score 0):

Is this answer any different in 1.5? In Python, whenever I write a function with several arguments, I usually call it with keyword arguments. It doesn't seem like there's a clean way to do that in Julia without either (1) giving them default values (could be sentinal values, as suggested by Iain) or (2) making them mandatory keyword arguments (as suggested by gTcV).